# JavaScript - What is the opposite of isNaN?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am very new to JavaScript, and trying to run a simple script which gives my field a red border if it is incorrectly completed (i.e. if the entry is not a number), but then turns the border colour green if the field is then correctly completed, but the form cannot be submitted because a different field has been filled out incorrectly.

So far i have managed to do this for a text field by using this:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["FN"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be completed");
  document.forms["myForm"]["FN"].style.border="1px solid red";
  return false;
  }
  else (x!==null || x!=="")
  {
  document.forms["myForm"]["FN"].style.border="1px solid green";
  }
```

but I am now trying to do the same thing but limit the field to only accept numbers.  What I have so far is this:

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value;
if (isNaN(x) || x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Contact number must be completed with numbers only");
  document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].style.border="1px solid red";
  return false;
  }
  else (x!==null || x!=="" || // need to write here is not isNaN !isNaN//)
  {
  document.forms["myForm"]["SN"].style.border="1px solid green";
  }
```

This restricts the fie;ld to only allowing numbers, but once the form box border turns red, it will not turn to green once the validation has been met.

Any help/tips on how to write is not isNaN, or any work arounds would be appreciated.

Please try to keep as simple as poss, as am a complete beginner with web design & JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: The opposite of `isNaN` is `!isNaN`, reads like: "isn't not a number" therefore, it's a number.

Comment: Why don't you just use an `else` clause that makes no further tests? That would result in code running when the not-a-number test **fails**, which means it must *be* a number.

Comment: @Pointy: how _can_ an else clause make a test?

Comment: Yeah, that syntax is not right now that I notice...

Comment: i managed to get this working using else (x>=0 || x!==null || x!==""), but as this is a contact number, it should allow space breaks in between the numbers (i.e. 0800 123 456 rather than 0800123456).  Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Comment: Though this is a different method (doesn't address the isNaN Q) and there are much more involved solutions, you could try to just test with a regex. something like this allows for numbers and spaces: if(!/^[0-9\s]+$/.test(x))

Comment: Well, I think what OP was getting at is that it is funky to use double negation. `!isNaN` means it's not not a number. So he was asking if there a `isaN` function.

Comment: Please don't use `!isNaN`. Everyone's brain who ends up reading this will thank you. Use `isFinite` or figure out some other way to avoid the double negative that is "not is not a number".

Answer (score 7):

The literal opposite of `isNaN(num)` is `!isNaN(num)`. However, this won't always verify that something is numeric. To check if something is numeric, use jQuery's `$.isNumeric(num)`, or this

```
function isNumeric(num) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num);
}
```

Comment: everything is `jQuery`

Answer (score 3):

If your code **really** looks like this:

```
  else (x>=0 || x!==null || x!=="")
  {
    document.forms["myForm"]["SN"].style.border="1px solid green";
  }
```

then your problem really has nothing to do with `isNaN`.  Syntactically, your `else` clause only applies to that parenthesized test expression. That expression will be evaluated when the `if` clause is `false`. It will have no effect on anything, however; the value will just be thrown away. The subsequent block statement in which the border is made green will *always* be executed; it has nothing to do with the `if - else` statement.

The syntax for the `else` clause in JavaScript does not involve a test condition like the `if` clause does. After an `else` should come a statement. In your case, that "statement" is the parenthesized test expression, which while useless is a perfectly valid statement in JavaScript.

Comment: well spotted, perhaps he meant to use `else **if**`

Answer (score 2):

Since **ECMAScript 2015** use [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) to check if a value is a number. You may need to call [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) before that if your value is of a string type.

For example `let isNumber = Number.isFinite(parseInt(my_form_input.value));`

The polyfill for older browsers is

```
Number.isFinite = Number.isFinite || function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value);
}
```